# How can I reset the Android studio layout?

Tags: android-studio

[My Android Studio Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAxqR.png)

I'm so sad because my android sutios's layout is something strange.
In above screenshot, as you can see, the blue circled position is located at very right side of studio. I want to move it like the position that the arrow points but I don't know how to move it..

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd never get helpful result when used Window\Restore default layout
So I'd had to just clean up the Android Studio settings directory:

**On Windows**

```
C:\Users\*[USERNAME]*\.AndroidStudioXX
```

**On Mac**
Delete these using the terminal (usage: rm -rf folderpath):

```
~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioBeta
~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudioBeta
~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudioBeta
~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudioBeta
```

Answer (score 11):

Go to

> Window > Restore Default Layout.

Or you could try <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>,

Most of the time the reset workspace will be under Window or in other applications under

> Window > WorkSpace > Reset Default Layout.

Then it should work!

Comment: This does not work for me on __Mac OS El Capitan__ and __Android Studio 2.2__.

Comment: Wow, still not working on MacOS in 2022 ...

Answer (score 3):

On a Mac

Delete these using the terminal (usage: rm -rf folderpath):

```
~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioBeta
~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudioBeta
~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudioBeta
~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudioBeta
```

Comment: Helped me in mac

Answer (score 2):

to move the toolbar back to the left side check 'toolbar' in the View menu.

On AS3.0 unchecking toolbar in the View menu moves it to the right of the screen. Deleting the settings didn't restore it to the correct position for me

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac:
File -> Manage IDE Settings -> Restore Default Settings

It worked on Android Studio Electric Eel

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is work in windows 10 too. But this solution need update android studio tool, sdk and jdk too.