# Android Studio displaying function name

Tags: android-studio

I was able to see the function name on the the Android Studio toolbar. I am not able to see it now and I cannot find where it is to toggle that. any idea?

[image]

More or less where the red circle is.

Comment: Can you add a picture of the GUI part where you saw the function name?

Comment: See edited question

Comment: Above. I don't remember exactly. But I remember I used to see the function name where the cursor was.

Comment: Was there one more line with some text? How did it look like?

Comment: Try to restore default view in Window this may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35823478/how-can-i-reset-the-android-studio-layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to "File" - "Settings" - Editor" - "General" - "Appearance" and check "Show breadcrumbs".

Comment: That is what I meant, but in my Android Studio release it is: File, Settings, Editor, General, Breadcrumbs, Show breadcrumbs (you can also select to be displayed at the bottom or at the top). I understand why I wasn't able to find it. It is hidden a lot. Way too deep.