# How to set the view of Android Studio?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I was doing my own flutter project and I changed the view mode of Android Studio. Since I changed the view mode, I can only see the Android Studio look like this. I can't see the files, git, and setting icons.
[image]

However, I want to get back the original view mode of Android Studio like this. Please help me!
[image]

Comment: Take a look at this --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35823478/how-can-i-reset-the-android-studio-layout

Answer (score 1):

In file you will see an option named invalidate cache. Select it and select invalidate cache and restart. That should revert layout too i think

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but sadly it didn't work :(

Comment: In window there is an option named restore default layout. Please try that also